# Adding API test cases with Selenium UI test cases

Tags: c#, api, selenium-webdriver, nunit, restsharp

Info about my project:  c# , selenium 3.9 , Nunit , windows , VS 17 , RestSharp (for API)

1. **Project** is developed primarily for UI test cases but now I want to add **API** test cases as well , Adding additional API cases because they are time consuming if doing on UI level
2. **Issue** : Whenever I run my API cases then driver gets initialized and which invokes the browser , right after that my API test kicks off and at the end I see API tests is gone well and running successfully.
3. I know I have to change my implementation on Base class but I am not sure what I am suppose to do it so my framework clearly understand that when it to invoke driver and when to skip ?? (Or I am not sure if we can do this through Nunit annotations)
4. Expectation : when running UI cases driver should invoke and launch browser but when running API cases driver should NOT invoke and *should Not launch browse*r
5. Please see implementation :

ValidateUI.cs : BaseTest

```
[TestFixture]

public class ValidateUI : BaseTest
{

    [Test]
    public static void testUI()
    {

    }
```

### }

ValidateAPI.cs : BaseTest

```
[TestFixture]

public class ValidateAPI : BaseTest
{

    [Test]
    public static void testAPI()
    {

    }
```

### }

BaseTest.cs

```
[TestFixture]
public class BaseTest
{        
    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        Driver.ConfigInit();
        Driver.LogStart();
        Driver.Initialize(Settings.BrowserType);
        LoginPage.GoTo(Settings.BrowserType);
    }
      [TearDown]
    public void Cleanup()
    {      
        Driver.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the API tests to use the driver, then you shouldn't derive the API fixture from BaseTest where the driver is set up.

You might try an inheritance hierarchy like this...

```
Base Fixture
    API Base Fixture
        API Test Fixture 1
        API Test Fixture 2
            etc.
    UI Base Fixture
        UI Test Fixture 1
        UI Test Fixture 1
```

Base Fixture would set up logging and other common stuff.

UI Base would set up drivers, etc.

API Base would do whatever setup your API tests need

This kind of partitioning of setup is exactly what fixtures are intended to do.

Comment: I am taking BaseTest because that's where I am kicking off log for everything. I worked around to keep Log in different class but that didn't work me, thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: The point is, the base of your inheritance hierarchy should only do those things that you want done for all tests. See edited answer for one hypothetical organization.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, I have done this fixture changes (now I have two Base classes one for  API and other for UI ) and it worked for me, thank you very much for your time, Earlier I was thinking I should not have two base classes but did not find work around.